# convert string value in to integer

Tags: java

How to convert string value into integer and multiply the converted value to integer so that I can get the result as 300.00. See example below -

```
int value = 5;
String  str = "60.00 Cur";
```

If I code like these then I am getting error -

```
Float f = new Float(app.price.get(position));           
double d = f.doubleValue();                 
int i = (int)d;
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the question?

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following code and see if this is what you want? The final answer will be present in the variable "result".

```
String str = "60.00 USD";
int value = 5;
String dollarValue = str.split(" ")[0];
Float price = Float.parseFloat(dollarValue );
Float result = price * value;

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
String resultString = df.format(result);
```

You will get a "NumberFormatException" if you try to `parseFloat` on str directly as it contains the string USD. Here we will split that and take the first part.

*Edit*: Try the newly added code with `DecimalFormat` and use the resultString for your purpose.

Comment: i want to get result as 300.00 it is getting as 300.0

Comment: I have updated the answer with some formatting using DecimalFormat. Can you try with this code?

Answer (score 2):

Use Interger.parseInt(String) or Float.parseFloat(String)

refer API documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Answer (score 2):

Use Integer.parseInt() method to convert to integer.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
int n = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().parse(str).intValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the String only contains numeric values you can use

Integer.parseInt(string); or
Float.parseFloat(string);

As for your example, the "USD" part will cause this to fail, so you'll probbaly have to strip this part out first.

e.g. string.split(" ");

Answer (score 0):

you will get a `NumberFormatException` as `"60.00 USD"` is not a float. To make it right you have to remove the currency. There can be many ways to remove the usd. For example

```
String s = "60.00 USD";
s = s.replace(" USD" , "");
```

or if the currency is not fixed

```
s = s.split(" ")[0];
```

Now you have A string s whose value is `"60.00"`

so you can do this now

```
float f = Float.parseFloat(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
 Integer.parseInt("value you want to parse as int")
```

likewise you can use,

```
Double.parseDouble("value");
```

This is answer for your Question

```
int result = Integer.parseInt("150.00 USD")* Integer.parseInt("5");
```